# Regex to store a word before and after in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium, regex-lookarounds

I'm doing a selenium scripting. So for that in the string "1 - 8 of 8 items". I have to find the number before the word "of" and number after the word "of" store it in two variables and check if it's equal.

So for that first I took the value before "of" using the regex "of\s+\b(\w+)\b" and value after "of" using the regex "(\S+)\s*of". The problem I face is when I use this regex the result comes with the word "of" (8 of, of 8). What regex can I use to get the value before and after "of" (8,8) without including the word "of". This is using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will get you the number just before `of`:

```
"1 - 7 of 8 items".match(/\d+(?=\s+of\s+)/)
```

Comment: This answer helped me more used "(/\d+(?=\s+of\s+)/)" to find the first 8 and (/\d+(?=\s+items\s+)/) to find the second 8. Thanks

Comment: Sure - Matching separately is no guarantee on the location of the literals matched between regexes. I.e. there is no real before and after. Doing it this way is a conceptual error.

Comment: @sln, thanks. I see your point, but in this specific case, the text is unlikely to change since it's likely a pager. So having only unique words, I don't see where a positive look ahead could be wrong or be a conceptual error. I'm probably wrong, so feel free to provide an example or link to some documentation.

Comment: Oh, documentation. I provide my documentation in my answers. But, I don't know where or how target text is generated. I do know that if it's not critical, you'd see a lot of junk expressions. I miss the day's before plastic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert at regex but I tried.

```
var findings  = "1 - 8 of 8 items 1 - abc of ghi items".match(/\w+ of \w+/g);
var collection = [];
findings.forEach(function(item){
    var words = item.split(' ');
    collection.push({first: words[0], second: words[2]});
});

console.log(collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'1 - 8 of 8 items'.match(/of\s+\b(\w+)\b/)[1]` gives the first `8`.

`'1 - 8 of 8 items'.match(/(\S+)\s*of/)[1]` gives the second `8`.

### Alternative

I would write them as follows:

`'1 - 8 of 8 items'.match(/(\d+) of/)[1]` for the first.

`'1 - 8 of 8 items'.match(/of (\d+)/)[1]` for the second.

Comment: When I tried your answer in a regex tester it shows an error that "/" is an unescaped delimiter

Comment: That's odd. I checked them again by pasting them in firebug, and got no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string at non-digits:

```
var ar = "1 - 8 of 8 items".split(/[^\d]+/)
```

which gives

```
Array [ "1", "8", "8", "" ]
```

Now you can compare the 2nd and 3rd element of the array

```
ar[1] == ar[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no use doing it separately, it can give the wrong result.

Find both at the same time.  `(\d+)\s+of\s+(\d+)`.
Before is in capture group 1, after is in capture group 2.

Do a search. If you don't know how to access the capture groups, do some reading.

Comment: Ok I will check on that. Thanks